# Difference between social networks and social media?

Tags: word-choice, difference

What is the difference between "social networks" and "social media"? I often see these two terms used, and I can't figure out when to use one or the other. I also wanted to know if the natives could tell the difference, or it is commonly misused.

Comment: There's no such word as _medias_, because _media_ is already plural (it's the Latin plural of _medium_ as in _medium of communication_).

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected

Comment: A "social network" could be anything, but "social media" usually refers to commercial internet sites run by well-known hosting companies.